# Hide children element without height impact

Tags: jquery, height, show-hide

I have list of anchor html controls. I need to hide specific anchor element, which is working fine but its position remains as it is.

This is my code

```
$("#warnings").children("a").hide().filter(".Other").show();
```

[**Fiddle Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/mtp6pozm/4/)

I want to show all visible anchor should be at top.

Comment: its bcoz u have added `br` after each `a` tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of the `br` elements

```js
var $as = $("#warnings").children("a");
$as.next('br').addBack().hide();
$as.filter(".Other").next('br').addBack().show();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="warnings">
  <h4>Warning(s)</h4>
  <p>Please select the warning(s) item to navigate to appropriate control</p>
  <a href="#" class="subject">Subject</a>
  <br> <a href="#" class="subject">Subject</a>
  <br> <a href="#" class="Contract">Contract</a>
  <br> <a href="#" class="Contract">Subject</a>
  <br> <a href="#" class="Contract">Contract</a>
  <br> <a href="#" class="Site">Site</a>
  <br> <a href="#" class="Site">Site</a>
  <br> <a href="#" class="Site">Site</a>
  <br> <a href="#" class="View">View</a>
  <br> <a href="#" class="View">View</a>
  <br> <a href="#" class="Other">Other</a>
</div>
```

---

Another easier solution is to use a calss

```js
$("#warnings").children("a").addClass('hidden').filter(".Other").removeClass('hidden');
```

```css
#warnings a.hidden,
#warnings a.hidden + br {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="warnings">
  <h4>Warning(s)</h4>
  <p>Please select the warning(s) item to navigate to appropriate control</p>
  <a href="#" class="subject">Subject</a>
  <br> <a href="#" class="subject">Subject</a>
  <br> <a href="#" class="Contract">Contract</a>
  <br> <a href="#" class="Contract">Subject</a>
  <br> <a href="#" class="Contract">Contract</a>
  <br> <a href="#" class="Site">Site</a>
  <br> <a href="#" class="Site">Site</a>
  <br> <a href="#" class="Site">Site</a>
  <br> <a href="#" class="View">View</a>
  <br> <a href="#" class="View">View</a>
  <br> <a href="#" class="Other">Other</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `<br />` and add CSS:

```
#warnings a {
    display: block;
}
```

That will make all `<a>` appear on their own line